# FFTW 3.3 compile error using NVCC on Linux

Tags: cuda, makefile, fftw, nvcc

every one,

I am trying to use NVCC to compile the following code that uses FFTW3.3 library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

void main() {

    fftwf_complex a;
    a[0] = 1;
    a[1] = -1;

    printf("a = %f %f, Testing FFTW with NVCC\n", a[0], a[1]);

}
```

When I compile using gcc it works fine:

```
cc main.cpp -o main.out  -lfftw3 -lm
main.out
a = 1.000000 -1.000000, Testing FFTW with CUDA
```

However, when I am trying to compile the same code as .cu file, using nvcc instead of gcc, 
I get a long list of compile errors:

```
nvcc main.cu -o main.out -lfftw3 -lm
/usr/include/fftw3.h(370): error: identifier "__float128" is undefined
/usr/include/fftw3.h(370): error: identifier "__float128" is undefined
...
```

Removing the two libraries -lfftw3 -lm would result in an undefined symbol of fftwf_complex.

Can anyone figure out what's going on?

Comment: what OS?  which version of cuda?  what version of gcc?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, CUDA5.5, gcc 4.6.3. I have got a work-around as suggested by @talonmies. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem in FFTW 3.3 whereby the FFTW headers misidentify that they are being compiled with a gcc version >=4.6 which has 128bit floating point support. It has been reported to effect compilation with icc, and it looks like nvcc steered compilation has the same problem.

The recommended workaround is to upgrade to FFTW 3.3.2.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made an upgrade and solve the problem.

Comment: I'm affected by this in FFTW 3.3.4, GCC 4.9.2, and CUDA 6.5.19.

Comment: @rubenvb: GCC 4.9 isn't a supported compiler for CUDA 6.5, so I wouldn't expect it to work correctly irrespective of whatever may or may not be a problem with FFTW

Comment: My point is it isn't fixed in FFTW 3.3.2, not even in 3.3.4, which was released in March 2014, before [the fix was merged in July 2014](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/issues/18). GCC 4.9 works quite well with CUDA, just as it works with older Matlab releases (which also "depend" on older GCC versions). It's just NVIDIA not officially "supporting" it because they're too lazy to actually test it.